# How do I handle validation and display suitable error boxes?

Tags: c#, textbox, messagebox

I need a program that will perform the following:

1. If i type in my textbox a bigger number then 6 then there must be a messagebox.
2. If i don't type a correct date of birth in my textbox2 then there must be also a messagebox. an example of a correct date of birth "01-05-1995".

Can someone help me? I'm not very good at c# but I am learning it!

Comment: I see that you have the "Informed" badge, and thus have read the tour pages. So you should know that you need to improve this question, to show what you have tried, researched, or what you think your approach should be, where you got stuck, and what specifically you need help with.

Comment: _"01-05-1995"_ - Is that _1st May 1995_ or _5th January 1995_?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!   _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Answer (score 0):

**This is a rough guide to help you find your own answer.**

Add an `on-change type` of even handler to the `textbox`.
In there read value of textbox and check if it's greater than 6 and show message.

Add an `lost focus type` of even handler to the `textbox2`.
In there read value of textbox2 and convert string to date.
If conversion success, and in range of valid Date of Births, good. Else show message box.

Comment: Though arguably a fine answer, consider adding a code sample to help illustrate your idea

Comment: @MickyDuncan, Hello good sir. I am assuming that OP is new to c#  programming and due to the lack of code in his question I kept my answer on the lines of "guiding him towards the answer". Lettting him do his research and work for the code.

Comment: Perhaps.  He might not know what _"on-change type of even handler"_ means.   I suspect OP is after code but SO-aside, I do agree with you regarding _"guiding him towards the answer"_.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the  `Integer.TryParse` and  `DateTime.TryParse` function to verify the input and parse them.

Documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Pseudo-code:

```
int iTextBox;
DateTime dDate;

if (!Integer.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out iTextBox) || iTextBox > 6)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show "Error in textbox1";
}

if (!DateTime.TryParse(textbox2.Text, out dDate))
{
    MessageBox.Show "Error in textbox2";
}
```